# Narrow search by tag

Tags: support, search

I love the site, but searching is a bit of a pain.
Lets say I want to figure out how to do something with databases in android.
I type in android sqlite, and get results for android, iphone, java, etc.
It would be nice to be able to just type in sqlite, and then select a tag to narrow it by.
So click Android and then only the android articles that include sqlite will show up.

If it already does this and I haven't figured it out let me know.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just search for:

```
[android] sqlite
```

Surround the tag name you want in square brackets.

Like the following search:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+sqlite

Answer (score 1):

See the search help page

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

It is linked from every search result page in the sidebar where it says "see our search tips", etc, as well as the /faq.